# Java Compile NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

So I'm trying to compile and run a problem in java and I can't get it to run. I'm just trying to do a basic package with a HelloWorld class and a main function that prints "hello world."

```
package helloworld;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world \n");
    }
}
```

then I call javac HelloWorld.java to compile it. Then when I try to execute the code I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: helloworld/HelloWorld)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Edit:
I am trying to run the code using the command "java HelloWorld"

Comment: R u trying to run using command/IDE?

Comment: I'm trying to run it using "java HelloWorld"

Comment: try to remove the package statement

Comment: I need the package statement for what I'm actually working on, this is just a simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets see if you understand what I did

```
tmp$ mkdir helloworld
tmp$ vi helloworld/HelloWorld.java
#paste the content of the class *including* package definition
tmp$ cd helloworld/
helloworld$ javac HelloWorld.java 
helloworld$ java HelloWorld 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: helloworld/HelloWorld)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld.  Program will exit.
helloworld$ cd ..
tmp$ java helloworld.HelloWorld 
Hello world
```

Also, read this: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/java.tools.html

Comment: basically you need to do `java helloworld.HelloWorld` instead of `java helloworld/HelloWorld`

Comment: wouldn't you need to specify that helloworld.HelloWorld is inside the helloworld/ directory? What would you change if the method was in a folder like "Test/"

Comment: package are nothing but directory structure. If you change folder `helloword` to `Test`, I assume you want to change package from `helloworld`" to `Test`

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps
1. Copy the HelloWorld.java file to a empty directory
2. javac -d . HelloWorld.java
3. java -classpath . helloworld.HelloWorld

There were 2 problems with your setup.
1. you need to use -d option while compiling. This will generate .class files according to the package structure. This is useful for running the .class file. This is so because java expects .class files in package structure.
2. specify the classpath as '.' which stands for current directory to run the program.

you can also use this
1. javac -d c:\temp HelloWorld.java
3. java -classpath c:\temp helloworld.HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

just change your classname from Helloworld to any other(like hl) and run like this (assume in e drive)
E:>cd helloworld

E:\helloworld>javac hl.java

E:\helloworld>cd ..

E:>java helloworld.hl
Hello world